# Is Raspberry PI 2 B suitable for a real-time audio effects application?

Tags: audio, pi-2

I am about to start working on a project which involves
real-time audio processing for an audio effects application.
The application is supposed to acquire and process audio from 8 individual audio 
input channels at a sample rate of 48kHz. The audio
processing algorithm generates audio for 8 individual audio output
channels. The audio sample format is 16-bit signed LPCM. Since it's
for a real-time audio effects application, latency is also important.
If audio is looped from input to output without any processing, the
round-trip latency should not exceed 12ms.

The application should receive 256*8 input samples every 5.33ms (via an audio callback), 
process those samples and transmit 256*8 output samples (also via callback). 
The 256*8 samples are received/sent in some kind of "interleaved" format.

I am currently researching different hardware platforms and I was wondering
if the Raspberry PI 2 B could be a suitable choice. The board itself seems
to have a lot of horse power (900MHz Quad Core ARM CPU), but it only has 
audio input. So my questions are:

1. Is the Raspberry PI 2 B suitable for real-time audio processing?
2. If the answer to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD0by.png) is yes, then I would like to know if there are 
   any add-on audio boards for the Raspberry PI 2 B on the market with 8 input channels
   and 8 output channels? The board must support 48kHz sample rate.
3. If the answer to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD0by.png) or [2] is no, which HW platform would you recommend?

The reason why I'm looking at the Raspberry PI 2 B is the attractive price, but there
might be other types of boards on the market which are more suitable for this
kind of application.

[image: Block diagram]

Comment: Belongs to the Raspberry Pi site